# Unquote __FUNCTION__ macro in C++

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor, quotes

Is that possible to unquote `__FUNCTION__` macro?
I need to call function with same name from other object:

```
this->__FUNCTION__(params)
```

But function gives function name with quotes...

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Comment: If you add some infomation about *why* you think you need this, I'm failry certain a better solution, not using the preprocessor, can be found.

Comment: No it is not possible. Why do you need this?

Comment: @stijn just speculating: makro for a recursive function?

Comment: I think that would be useful for calling super-methods in virtual functions...