# Use __FUNCTION__ to call the function with the same name in another class

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I am trying to use a macro which takes advantage of the preprocessor `__FUNCTION__` to switch to calling a function by the same name as the macro caller, but in a different class.

(This is a simple mocking framework implemented without inheritance.)

```cpp
#define FAKE(def) enabled(__FUNCTION__) ? def : _foo.__FUNCTION__()
```

The usage is like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    int bar() { return 42; }
};

#define FAKE(def) enabled() ? def : _foo.__FUNCTION__()

struct Fake {
    Fake(Foo& foo) : _foo(foo) {}
    Foo& _foo;
    bool enabled(const char*) const { return true; } // for example
    int bar() {
        return FAKE(1337); // doesn't work
    }
};
```

which gives the error:

```
error: '__FUNCTION__' cannot be used as a function
```

This seems to be due to the fact that `__FUNCTION__` is not a macro but a string literal.

Is there an easy-ish workaround? I would prefer not to cache some mapping of strings to function pointers or something. I know C++ doesn't support reflection, but I was hoping the preprocessor could sort this out somehow.

### [Live example](http://cpp.sh/4tr45)

Comment: Another duplicate [Unquote \_\_FUNCTION__ macro in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36352289/unquote-function-macro-in-c) with "not possible" comments.

Comment: `#define FAKE(R, FUNC, DEFAULT)  R FUNC() { return enabled(__FUNCTION__)?DEFAULT:_foo.FUNC();  }` should work.  Might need `FUNCEX(R, FUNC, MODIFIERS, DEFAULT)` or the like.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there an easy-ish workaround?

No.

> I would prefer not to cache some mapping of strings to function pointers or something

If you want runtime dispatch, then this is the way to go.

> I know C++ doesn't support reflection, but I was hoping the preprocessor could sort this out somehow.

And because C++ does not support reflection, no language feature will "sort this out". The language itself does not support finding a function by it's string representation. Preprocessor is a (simple) string replacement tool. `__FUNCTION__` is not a string literal - `__FUNCTION__` works like as-if a `static const char *` variable would be defined in the function. Do not use `__FUNCTION__`, it's an extension, use `__func__`. In C++20 see [source_location](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location).

But there is no need to use reflection. In C++, use SFINAE. In C++17, there's `if constexpr`. In C++20, there are concepts. For example see [this answer to Templated check for the existence of a class member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/264088/9072753).